# Update the database field automatically after calculating the date?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a table in the database that holds two dates,

first field: startdate = "1400/01/08"
second field: enddate = after flowing calcute...

And in this table I have a field that is of the byte type

AllowField = "0"

1-I want to get today's date,If the months of todays date was between 01 and 06...

for example: var six1 =  "1400/01/01,

I want to multiply "six1" by "31":
for example: var resualt1 =  "1400/01/01 * 31 = 1400/02/01"
and saved "resualt1" in  "enddate" field

2-If the months of todays date was between 07 and 12...

for example: var six2 =  "1400/07/01,

I want to multiply "six2" by "30":
for example: var resualt2 =  "1400/07/01 * 30 = 1400/08/01"
and saved "resualt2" in  "enddate" field

And I want to load the form if today's date was not between "startdate" and "enddate"

"AllowField" Automatically change its value to 1 and Conversely؟

Comment: I cannot make sense of your date format... are you sure you are comparing dates in the middle ages to today? Does that make sense? Also... multiplying a date is not defined. You can add days, is that what you mean? Except that adding 31 days does not always end you on the same day of the next month. That is why there are functions to add months and years.

Comment: Also... what *can* you do so far? Can you read from the database? Can you do your logic on the variable in your code? Can you update the database? Where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: First I want to get today next month,But because the first 6 months are 31 days And the second 6 months is 30 days,I must first determine if today's date is the first 6 months or the second 6 monthsوAnd so I can get the same day next month

Comment: What? That is not how a calendar works *at all*. Februar has 28 or sometimes even 29 days for example.

Comment: Your code and description have so many logic errors, that I would advise you to first sit down with pencil and paper and think about what you want and try it with a few dates, before starting any programming. There is nothing a computer can do for you, if you don't have a sound understanding of what you *want* it to do for you. If the calculation in your head is wrong, it won't get magically right on a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) class in C# has a method called [AddMonths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=net-6.0).

```
var thisDayNextMonth = currentDate.AddMonths(1);
```

Please do not homebrew a weird solution. Standard problems have standard solutions and in C# they are really easy to find and not obscure at all.